# Static map api url with polyline gets uriEncoded from cordova file transfer plugin

Tags: cordova-plugins, ngcordova, google-maps-static-api

I've got a url that if you copy and paste into your browser shows a map:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&key=AIzaSyAzijDqcmwhL7jvqZ625ZfjU-WskiuVqko&size=1000x900&path=weight:12|color:0x037AFF|enc:c`sfEl~`jUzAkf@{_@aKuhAnMhBjiAkpB|nB_rAxaCooCto@esBzAkyAf|@o{AhpAsrAlS{bAZeiEej@kzC_UgfAx|@_zA~g@goDl\yyEvaAwsBlnAo_Bdp@irBr}@}kEz|@uyH~}DodF|iBooDnlCgj@trAe{CjiBggArxAowAzdAskGfsFy{AdoB}aAjVivG|gKevAp|CwsA~~B{}E`cCgrBnvCsmBf`E_Zla@ooAeh@ccAsq@ibA_BqeCz|@{Vn\_u@z@ieCcGinDiGoz@nb@ak@`{A_`AdiBwmCfdCcqEt|Cw`Cj|AitCxaCkeBpsCcqAtjD_rAbxBqxDh~CksGfdH}dFn}LiaGxbLekEv`Da`CvgCceC`bB}qCzpCo}@~sC}r@~qDsp@tm@uwA_d@wmDpd@{bDnmEep@nrAm{@bb@}cDjn@cf@|w@uwB`oBi{BxtC}oBloBox@bdAuHvfAoV|iB}hAnkDajGx}F{wGtfH{m@hZol@jzAirBbbEc}F|rBw|CthA{cAv|@iv@j|As`Avh@ylDeDkyF`fE_gC|gBi`BveBovAdmBaeBvuAqxAHuuAb\kyApyAsIjz@yl@t}@_|Btt@c_AliAcoBnlBmtA`f@yzCjWwqDqPohAnh@aoCx{Esa@duEsqAlmA_xCoeCcaD`gBaxBbzBin@p_A}y@tlAiqA`FsqBx@goB~z@s|JntBs}AjbAg_EbfEup]lj`@ssObvPagHnrKotI||MweThm[edJzcKkfHfwGc`ElnCuyP|gLihVtuP{mT`mTu{HdvIa_CjoEkvBpqEwtEbvHsqEl_EwwIfzHyoEnfCmzKfbGcrDjvBufF`oEsuKljJscPhoNkuG~~HiqN|rSuiRliNa`VryN{xLlcIaxKrqMw}Np{MmTpOePfxOkoCvyFky@zlC_lAh~@vj@dmCp_AhhAfOjrDlk@|uAbt@dn@phBbeGri@nh@@dz@cKhnAvn@~z@pa@hgDpyBx}Bxs@zgDrtA`{Ajn@vMrg@cRxs@rJrXfu@lYdhAgaAnrBaMlnAwu@l]e]b~AdPru@mA`vBizB~jDy\`d@hi@r^bWfYc[pyBmGjjAyrJpxDwwEdsBs|BzaCkqEpbDsmBlpBm|B`lCuqD|xF}qEn|ImmAxlAsoBvn@qxB~m@yeBpbBcrC`mCcbB|gB{\hhDaz@~aDm`ErrWcq@`iDmeCfqDqzDbuFkeCh~F_o@pzE_d@~eBoqBlaCujGfhGmfD|dEuOvcDspBtjDcf@nk@_G{n@sKcQ&markers=color:0xFF8F00%7Clabel:A%7C32.70735640000002,-117.1564884&markers=color:0xFF8F00%7Clabel:B%7C37.62131290000001,-122.37895540000005&style=feature:landscape|hue:0xFFBB00|saturation:43.400000000000006|lightness:37.599999999999994|gamma:1&style=feature:road|hue:0xFFC200|saturation:-61.8|lightness:45.599999999999994|gamma:1&style=feature:road|hue:0xFF0300|saturation:-100|lightness:51.19999999999999|gamma:1&style=feature:road|hue:0xFF0300|saturation:-100|lightness:52|gamma:1&style=feature:water|hue:0x0078FF|saturation:-13.200000000000003|lightness:2.4000000000000057|gamma:1&style=feature:poi|hue:0x00FF6A|saturation:-1.0989010989011234|lightness:11.200000000000017|gamma:1
```

but when I pass this url into the `$cordovaFileTransfer.download` method, it runs `encodeURI` internally which then coverts the url to:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&key=AIzaSyAzijDqcmwhL7jvqZ625ZfjU-WskiuVqko&size=1000x900&path=weight:12%7Ccolor:0x037AFF%7Cenc:c%60sfEl~%60jUzAkf@%7B_@aKuhAnMhBjiAkpB%7CnB_rAxaCooCto@esBzAkyAf%7C@o%7BAhpAsrAlS%7BbAZeiEej@kzC_UgfAx%7C@_zA~g@goDl%5CyyEvaAwsBlnAo_Bdp@irBr%7D@%7DkEz%7C@uyH~%7DDodF%7CiBooDnlCgj@trAe%7BCjiBggArxAowAzdAskGfsFy%7BAdoB%7DaAjVivG%7CgKevAp%7CCwsA~~B%7B%7DE%60cCgrBnvCsmBf%60E_Zla@ooAeh@ccAsq@ibA_BqeCz%7C@%7BVn%5C_u@z@ieCcGinDiGoz@nb@ak@%60%7BA_%60AdiBwmCfdCcqEt%7CCw%60Cj%7CAitCxaCkeBpsCcqAtjD_rAbxBqxDh~CksGfdH%7DdFn%7DLiaGxbLekEv%60Da%60CvgCceC%60bB%7DqCzpCo%7D@~sC%7Dr@~qDsp@tm@uwA_d@wmDpd@%7BbDnmEep@nrAm%7B@bb@%7DcDjn@cf@%7Cw@uwB%60oBi%7BBxtC%7DoBloBox@bdAuHvfAoV%7CiB%7DhAnkDajGx%7DF%7BwGtfH%7Bm@hZol@jzAirBbbEc%7DF%7CrBw%7CCthA%7BcAv%7C@iv@j%7CAs%60Avh@ylDeDkyF%60fE_gC%7CgBi%60BveBovAdmBaeBvuAqxAHuuAb%5CkyApyAsIjz@yl@t%7D@_%7CBtt@c_AliAcoBnlBmtA%60f@yzCjWwqDqPohAnh@aoCx%7BEsa@duEsqAlmA_xCoeCcaD%60gBaxBbzBin@p_A%7Dy@tlAiqA%60FsqBx@goB~z@s%7CJntBs%7DAjbAg_EbfEup%5Dlj%60@ssObvPagHnrKotI%7C%7CMweThm%5BedJzcKkfHfwGc%60ElnCuyP%7CgLihVtuP%7BmT%60mTu%7BHdvIa_CjoEkvBpqEwtEbvHsqEl_EwwIfzHyoEnfCmzKfbGcrDjvBufF%60oEsuKljJscPhoNkuG~~HiqN%7CrSuiRliNa%60VryN%7BxLlcIaxKrqMw%7DNp%7BMmTpOePfxOkoCvyFky@zlC_lAh~@vj@dmCp_AhhAfOjrDlk@%7CuAbt@dn@phBbeGri@nh@@dz@cKhnAvn@~z@pa@hgDpyBx%7DBxs@zgDrtA%60%7BAjn@vMrg@cRxs@rJrXfu@lYdhAgaAnrBaMlnAwu@l%5De%5Db~AdPru@mA%60vBizB~jDy%5C%60d@hi@r%5EbWfYc%5BpyBmGjjAyrJpxDwwEdsBs%7CBzaCkqEpbDsmBlpBm%7CB%60lCuqD%7CxF%7DqEn%7CImmAxlAsoBvn@qxB~m@yeBpbBcrC%60mCcbB%7CgB%7B%5ChhDaz@~aDm%60ErrWcq@%60iDmeCfqDqzDbuFkeCh~F_o@pzE_d@~eBoqBlaCujGfhGmfD%7CdEuOvcDspBtjDcf@nk@_G%7Bn@sKcQ&markers=color:0xFF8F00%257Clabel:A%257C32.70735640000002,-117.1564884&markers=color:0xFF8F00%257Clabel:B%257C37.62131290000001,-122.37895540000005&style=feature:landscape%7Chue:0xFFBB00%7Csaturation:43.400000000000006%7Clightness:37.599999999999994%7Cgamma:1&style=feature:road%7Chue:0xFFC200%7Csaturation:-61.8%7Clightness:45.599999999999994%7Cgamma:1&style=feature:road%7Chue:0xFF0300%7Csaturation:-100%7Clightness:51.19999999999999%7Cgamma:1&style=feature:road%7Chue:0xFF0300%7Csaturation:-100%7Clightness:52%7Cgamma:1&style=feature:water%7Chue:0x0078FF%7Csaturation:-13.200000000000003%7Clightness:2.4000000000000057%7Cgamma:1&style=feature:poi%7Chue:0x00FF6A%7Csaturation:-1.0989010989011234%7Clightness:11.200000000000017%7Cgamma:1
```

To see one of the differences, look at the param `&path=weight:12`. Right after, you'll see the `|` character in the first string is `encoded` to `%7C` in the second string. The problem is that this encoded url gets a `404` on the Google Static Maps API.

Should the `$cordovaFileTransfer.download` have an option to NOT encode urls or is there some param I should be passing along with the URL to the Google Static Maps API that tells it to decode it?

**UPDATE**

I believe the issue isn't with encoding or anything like that but with the `length` of the encoded url. I tried removing the `&markers` param (and everything after) and it worked.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&key=AIzaSyAzijDqcmwhL7jvqZ625ZfjU-WskiuVqko&size=1000x900&path=weight:12%7Ccolor:0x037AFF%7Cenc:c%60sfEl~%60jUzAkf@%7B_@aKuhAnMhBjiAkpB%7CnB_rAxaCooCto@esBzAkyAf%7C@o%7BAhpAsrAlS%7BbAZeiEej@kzC_UgfAx%7C@_zA~g@goDl%5CyyEvaAwsBlnAo_Bdp@irBr%7D@%7DkEz%7C@uyH~%7DDodF%7CiBooDnlCgj@trAe%7BCjiBggArxAowAzdAskGfsFy%7BAdoB%7DaAjVivG%7CgKevAp%7CCwsA~~B%7B%7DE%60cCgrBnvCsmBf%60E_Zla@ooAeh@ccAsq@ibA_BqeCz%7C@%7BVn%5C_u@z@ieCcGinDiGoz@nb@ak@%60%7BA_%60AdiBwmCfdCcqEt%7CCw%60Cj%7CAitCxaCkeBpsCcqAtjD_rAbxBqxDh~CksGfdH%7DdFn%7DLiaGxbLekEv%60Da%60CvgCceC%60bB%7DqCzpCo%7D@~sC%7Dr@~qDsp@tm@uwA_d@wmDpd@%7BbDnmEep@nrAm%7B@bb@%7DcDjn@cf@%7Cw@uwB%60oBi%7BBxtC%7DoBloBox@bdAuHvfAoV%7CiB%7DhAnkDajGx%7DF%7BwGtfH%7Bm@hZol@jzAirBbbEc%7DF%7CrBw%7CCthA%7BcAv%7C@iv@j%7CAs%60Avh@ylDeDkyF%60fE_gC%7CgBi%60BveBovAdmBaeBvuAqxAHuuAb%5CkyApyAsIjz@yl@t%7D@_%7CBtt@c_AliAcoBnlBmtA%60f@yzCjWwqDqPohAnh@aoCx%7BEsa@duEsqAlmA_xCoeCcaD%60gBaxBbzBin@p_A%7Dy@tlAiqA%60FsqBx@goB~z@s%7CJntBs%7DAjbAg_EbfEup%5Dlj%60@ssObvPagHnrKotI%7C%7CMweThm%5BedJzcKkfHfwGc%60ElnCuyP%7CgLihVtuP%7BmT%60mTu%7BHdvIa_CjoEkvBpqEwtEbvHsqEl_EwwIfzHyoEnfCmzKfbGcrDjvBufF%60oEsuKljJscPhoNkuG~~HiqN%7CrSuiRliNa%60VryN%7BxLlcIaxKrqMw%7DNp%7BMmTpOePfxOkoCvyFky@zlC_lAh~@vj@dmCp_AhhAfOjrDlk@%7CuAbt@dn@phBbeGri@nh@@dz@cKhnAvn@~z@pa@hgDpyBx%7DBxs@zgDrtA%60%7BAjn@vMrg@cRxs@rJrXfu@lYdhAgaAnrBaMlnAwu@l%5De%5Db~AdPru@mA%60vBizB~jDy%5C%60d@hi@r%5EbWfYc%5BpyBmGjjAyrJpxDwwEdsBs%7CBzaCkqEpbDsmBlpBm%7CB%60lCuqD%7CxF%7DqEn%7CImmAxlAsoBvn@qxB~m@yeBpbBcrC%60mCcbB%7CgB%7B%5ChhDaz@~aDm%60ErrWcq@%60iDmeCfqDqzDbuFkeCh~F_o@pzE_d@~eBoqBlaCujGfhGmfD%7CdEuOvcDspBtjDcf@nk@_G%7Bn@sKcQ
```

What's interesting is that I've read there is a `2048` character limit on urls for the Google Maps API. The first url above is `2096` characters and the second is `2387` characters. I'm kind of stumped as to why the first one worked at all...

Comment: Max dimensions for free license is 640x640. It's useless to try 1000x900

Comment: URL length limit is now 8192 characters. I just tried your URL-encoded URL and it showed a good-looking map.